# How can I get Powershell tab completion for array parameters?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Currently, I'm trying using the ValidateSet attribute declaration as so:

```
function cmdlet {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateSet("option_1", "option_2", "option_3")]
        [string[]] $options
    )

    ...
}
```

Using this, I can tab-complete a unit-length parameter, i.e.

```
> cmdlet <TAB> -> cmdlet option_1
```

But to get further options to tab complete (or, indeed parse correctly) I have to wrap the previous parameters in quotes, i.e.

```
> cmdlet option_1<TAB> -> cmdlet option_1
```

(fails to tab-complete)

```
> cmdlet "option_1",<TAB><TAB> -> cmdlet "option_1",option_2
```

(executes correctly)

```
> cmdlet option_1,option_2<ENTER>
cmdlet : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'options'. The argument "o" does not belong to the set "option_1,option_2,option_3" specified by the ValidateSet attribute.
Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:8
+ cmdlet option_1,option_2
+        ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [cmdlet], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,cmdlet
```

This is obviously less than ideal. Either I'd like the tab completion to wrap the arguments in quotes for me (Or to not require them at all, but I imagine that'll be harder).

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to wrap the first arg in quotes, just add a comma after the first completion and then press the tab key again to add more values. Regardless of quotes, your function works for me without a problem. Not sure why "o" is passed on. I would restart the console and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you want, but you could use ParameterSetName to create a collection of mutually exclusive switches:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName="Option_1")] 
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Option_1")]
    [switch]$Option_1,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Option_2")]
    [switch]$Option_2,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Option_3")]
    [switch]$Option_3
)
```

In the example I have set the default to Option_1, but you could omit this to make all of them optional, if you specify more than one you will get an error.